# Git: add file to old commit being parent of a new branch already merged back?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit, git-rebase

given the following git log, how do i add a file (which never existed in any commit) to commit B, so that this new file will appear in every other commit that A?

```
A --> B -----> D ------> F
       \--> C --> E --/
```

In my attempts with git rebase --onto i did not succeed in not having to essentially duplicate every commit amending the contents but i am sure i am not approaching it using the full power of git. Any help?

Note: remote is fine to be forced, or even deleted and pushed again, that's not a worry.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end result will be that : duplicating all the commits.

About the ways to do it, though, you can use `git rebase` with some options :

```
# -i for --interactive
# -r for --rebase-merges
git rebase -i -r A
```

`git` will open a text editor for you, asking you to describe what actions you want to take on each commit.

In that file :

- find the line mentioning commit `B`
- change the action from `pick` to `edit`
- save and exit

`git` will start applying the script you instructed him to, and will pause after reaching `B`.

At this point, you can add the extra file :

- `git add` the file you want
- `git commit --amend` to add it to `B`
- `git rebase --continue` to proceed with the rebase

This should rewrite all the commits after `B`.

You can check your local history, and the content of your commits,
if you are satisfied with the result you can `push --force`.

Comment: Hi, i just tried and i think this could be a solution even if following your steps i ended up with a sort of split history. A is the ancestor of B and B', where B is still parent of D and B' is a new parent of C. Any idea why? It seems the edit of B has not affected the C-E branch. Interestingly F, the original merge-back commit seems to be gone.

Comment: Mission Accomplished. Please edit your answer and add --preserver-merges (deprecated, but the one i used) or, even better, --rebase-merges to the rebase command. This will preserve the merges and will not flat down the tree!

Comment: Done. I had mixed my options up, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

[`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) could be of help. It can rewrite a range of commits at once. From your note I take that you are aware of the potential problems wrt. commit rewriting of shared history (different hashes, etc.)

NB. It can't hurt to create a backup copy before trying this :)

```
git filter-branch \
  --index-filter 'cp /path/to/new/file path/in/repo && git add path/in/repo/file' \
  -- A..F
```

This applies the filter to all commits reachable from `F`, but excluding any commits reachable from `A` (in other words: excluding `A` and all ancestors of it)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Looking into the docs filter-branch seems to be a potential nightmare and causes, in any event, the presence of extra unwanted entities in the rewritten repo. Anyway you inspired me to look into https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo as the doc suggests and i will give it a try today!